# Create a (view)point perpendicular to another point on a line

Tags: qgis, point, line

I need to create a view point for each point in my map, I can create a single-sided buffer for the original line my points are on, but I don't know how to project the points in a perpendicular way on the boundary of the single-sided buffer. Any ideas or is the single-sided buffer not the right starting point?

Here is a picture what I want to archive:

[image: viewpoint for my original point on a line]

I just need the red point, the yellow and white line is just for explanations.

Comment: Buffer, convert to line, then get the closest points on that bufferline from your points.

Comment: hey thanks for the reminder that the closest point is the one with 90 degree!
But instead of getting the closest points in that buffer line, I just snapped my points to the buffer line (with the option nearest). Was a bit easier in QGIS!